# symfony2: trying to add a type="number" attribute to a form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have this field,

```
 ->add('number', 'number', array(
'label' => false,
'attr' => array('class' => 'producto', 'type' => 'number')))
```

I expected a `type="number"` attribute to be added, increase and decrease the number inside with the little arrows down/up, but I get an input with type="text" attribute:

```
<input type="text" value="11" class="producto form-control" required="required" name="project_backendbundle_pedido[pedidoSubitems][0][number]" id="project_backendbundle_pedido_pedidoSubitems_0_number">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `type` attribute is set via the widget type you choose. To get a `type="number"` you need to choose `integer` as widget type. Confusing, I know..

But have a look at the [official symfony page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html). So your code should look like this:

```
->add('number', 'integer', array(
    'label' => false,
    'attr'  => array('class' => 'producto'),
))
```

Comment: The problem with integer is that you cannot receive decimal number (ex: 12,5)

Comment: Indeed but as described in form_div_layout.html.twig inside the block 'number_widget' the input type="number" doesn't work with floats

Comment: Input type number does work with floats but would need to have the `step` attribute declared of an appropriate `scale` to use for the form field. Browser support for the `number` form field and `step` is unreliable and thus would require a text field for it to work consistently across all browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Answer (score 0):

To have a type number you need to do(for symfony 2.8):

In form builder use these parameters:

```
->add('fixedCharge', 'number', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'rounding_mode' => 0,
                    'precision' => 2,
                    'scale' => 7,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'min' => -90,
                        'max' => 90,
                        'step' => 0.01,
                    ),
                ))
```

In twig define explicitly as number:

```
{{ form_widget(form.fixedCharge, { 'type':'number' }) }}
```

Additionally, for  browsers that ignore HTML5 validation, you can also add a server side validation on the entity field:

```
@Assert\Type(type="float", message="must be a numeric value")
```